# How to integrate Spline into a react website while using Vercel for deployment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, vercel, spline

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { content } from "../Content";
import Spline from '@splinetool/react-spline';
// import Keyboard from "./components/Keyboard.jsx";

const Hero = () => {
    const { hero } = content;
    const [showContent, setShowContent] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleScroll = () => {
            const threshold = window.innerHeight / 2;
            const isScrolled = window.scrollY > threshold;
            setShowContent((prev) => (isScrolled ? true : prev));
        };

        handleScroll();
        window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <section id="home" className="relative overflow-hidden">
            <div className="min-h-screen relative flex md:flex-row flex-col-reverse md:items-end justify-center items-center">
                <div
                    className={`absolute h-full md:w-4/12 w-8/12 top-0 right-0 bottom-0 z-10 ${
                        showContent ? "opacity-100 translate-x-0" : "opacity-0 translate-x-10"
                    } bg-primaryLinear`}
                >
                    <h2 className="rotate-90 absolute top-[30%] right-[15%]" style={{ fontSize: '3rem' }}>{hero.title}</h2>
                </div>

                {showContent && (
                    <>
                        <Spline scene="https://prod.spline.design/HKlfAoUoTv3w35yQ/scene.splinecode" />

                        {/* <Keyboard /> */}
                    </>
                )}

                <div className={`pb-16 px-6 pt-12 z-10 text-center-mobile ${showContent ? "opacity-100 translate-y-0" : "opacity-0 translate-y-10"}`}>
                    <br />
                    <div className="flex flex-col gap-10 mt-10">
                        {hero.hero_content.map((content, i) => (
                            <div
                                key={i}
                                className={`flex items-center w-80
                                    ${i === 1 && " flex-row-reverse text-right flex-col-reverse-mobile"}
                                `}
                                style={{ transitionDelay: `${i * 300}ms` }}
                            >
                                <h3>{content.count}</h3>
                                <p>{content.text}</p>
                            </div>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    );
};

export default Hero;
```

> This is a file on my website, I need some assistance with implementing my Spline project in while making sure it still runs on my Vercel deployment. The only problem is it has an issue with the `@` format of the spline input and nothing else works. My website is supposedly missing a node_modules file but adding it caused more issues than it solved and I am still able to download files into my `GitHub` repository. If anyone has had a similar problem please help. I can adjust my question to be more helpful if people need it but this is pretty much all the info I have.